# Unable to list audit devices with "sudo" and "list" capabilities applied to token policy

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to issue a vault CLI call to list the currently enabled audit devices. I have defined a policy against `sys/audit` which defines "sudo" and "list" capabilities (among others). I have been issued a token with that policy applied. However when I run `vault audit list`, I get a "permission denied" error.

What capabilities do I need to add to my policy in order for this to work? This is being done in a bootstrap script. (The additional capabilities currently included are because I do an 'enable' if the result of 'list' turns up that auditing is disabled. I'm trying to limit the permissions of this token to just the absolute minimum required for the two operations needed in this context.)

Policy (named "aud"):

```
path "sys/audit/*" {
  capabilities = ["list", "read", "create", "update", "sudo"]
}
```

Token issuance (done elsewhere, logged in with root token):

```
vault token create --id=my-token --policy=aud
```

My script (where I attempt to use the token to login and check audit device status):

```
vault login my-token
vault audit list
vault audit enable file <options>
```

Error:

```
Error listing audits: Error making API request.
  
URL: GET http://< obfuscated >:8200/v1/sys/audit
Code: 403. Errors:

* 1 error occurred:
  * permission denied
```

The subsequent 'vault audit enable' call works, so I know the capabilities are sufficient for that. But I'm unsure what change I need to make so that `vault audit list` works, since I already have "sudo" along with "list" and "read" capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that a wildcard policy for path `"sys/audit/*"` won't match against a request to `sys/audit` (no suffix). So in fact two separate path declarations are necessary.

First, for the `vault audit list`, this policy is sufficient:

```
path "sys/audit" {
  capabilities = ["list", "read", "sudo"]
}
```

... and then for `vault audit enable`, the broader policy against the wildcard:

```
path "sys/audit/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "update", "sudo"]
}
```

This second one could be tightened up to only match against `sys/audit/file` as well.